# Is there any difference between an "AMP Stack" and WAMP?

Tags: web-services

I appologize for my lack of knowledge but I am to set up a web server and need some help. As of right now I use Acquai Dev Desktop, that is I use Drupal with a "AMP stack". I've also read about wamp and I don't really get what the difference is. 
Appreciate any help possible!

Comment: All right thank you! It seems as if though I am not able to reach/find the Apache web server using Acquai Dev Desktop. I'd like to do some changes in it. Is this something you are familiar with?

Comment: There are plenty of Drupal users here, but most will run it on Linux I should think. If you have a _specific_ coding problem with Drupal, do ask it in a new question here, but it is a good idea to read the FAQ first (and make sure you show a reasonable attempt to solve it).

Comment: Yes I have done that but haven't found a solution that fits me. Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question hasn't been answered, transferring from and expanding upon my comment:

*AMP generally means either LAMP, MAMP or WAMP, with the initial letters referring to Linux, Mac and Windows respectively.

So, the written requirements is saying that Drupal requires Apache<sup>1</sup>, MySQL and PHP, but that it will run on any AMP-supporting OS. At the lower end of the market, Linux is cheaper to run, since you don't (in general) need to pay licensing fees, but as your requirements grow, you may have a reason to run Windows Server or OS X. PHP has traditionally run much better on Unix/Linux, but of late Zend and Microsoft have been improving stability and performance on Windows.

You can host on Mac as well, but in my view this is considered relatively niche. A number of hosts offer "Mac Mini hosting" on account of the number of machines that can be stored inside a server cabinet. I'd expect this to be perfectly stable, since the OS is based on Unix.

<sup>1</sup> Generally the requirement for Apache is just to use `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`. If you are confident about writing and using an IIS replacement, you can switch away from Apache if you wish.